# Does plane detection increase accuracy of Augmented Image Tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, point-clouds, arcore

I have an application for visualizing scan of a room and i am using an Augmented Image to align my points to real world. I am not using plane detection in my application so it is optional for me.

However, i have some questions regarding tracking accuracy because accuracy of my alignment at the moment solely depends on how accurate i can detect the center position and corners of the augmented image.

1. Does using plane detection increase accuracy of detecting an image position in an Augmented Image application?
2. Does it also affect accuracy of tracking and ARCore environmental understanding. Because users can move in the room and inspect the scan and also i tested my application with and without plane detection and it appears with plane detection my alignment changes over time because of ARCore environmental understanding and there is a shift in anchors. This does not happen that much without plane detection.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For those who visited this question. I asked it also on github issues for ARCore and the reply i got is this: `Currently, Augmented Images are detected through features and are found on a plane, so it is helpful to scan the environment from different angles, so that ARCore can estimate depth of visible feature points and determine whether they are on a common plane.

Actual detection of a plane is not required, but the feature points of the detected image to need to exist on a plane. That is, bending/folding a piece of paper will cause image detection to stop working`